# How to optimise images requested from Instagram, to satisfy PageSpeed Insights.

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization

I'm trying to improve my Pagespeed Score, however, my Instagram feed is causing google to suggest the images being fed through are not optimised and reducing my score considerably.

This is an integral part of the front page and doing without it is not really an option.

I'm running a WordPress web store.

Are there any solutions to compressing images coming other servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service like cloudinary.

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Jennifer_Lawrence_at_the_83rd_Academy_Awards.jpg
```

you can also control the jpg compression / quality.

Comment: The problem is that these images are directly being fed through an API call to Instagram.
But thank you for the above link, it does look very useful for future projects.

Comment: API call from javascript or PHP?